# POST request using XML in perl

Tags: xml, perl, post

Now I am getting that content type can't be consumed. here is the actual summary or scenario for workflow, The workflow needs to be more precise so that it explains itself for the exact:

Please suggest what am I doing wrong.

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request::Common;
my $sendXML="INPUT.XML";
my $resultXML="RESULT.XML";
my $message = <<'XML';
<criteria>
<includeFilterSets>
        <filterSet>
            <filter>
                <filterName>PRODUCT_NAME</filterName>
                </filterSet>
    </excludeFilterSets>
    </entityToSearch>
<criteria>
XML

my $webpage="http://example.com/";
#my $webpage = HTTP::Request->new(GET => 'http/Testlocation');
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new; 
my $response = $ua->post($webpage, Content_Type => 'text/xml', Content => $message);
if ($response->is_success) {
    print $response->decoded_content;  # or whatever
}
else {
    #die $response->status_line;
    print $response->decoded_content;

}
```

Comment: Please, give us a deeper explanation of your requeriments

Comment: So what's the problem? Constructing the XML? Putting it into an HTTP request? There are plenty of modules for both handling XML and for making HTTP requests on [cpan](https://metacpan.org/), most have pretty good documentation. Which modules have you selected? What about the documentation don't you understand?

Comment: I have shared my Inputs regarding my problem.Please suggest.

Comment: there @Quentin.Suggest please.i hope that you have got my problem now.

Comment: there @MiguelPrz.Suggest please

Comment: Also. i have tried the following code and getting error message as "Content type" can't be consumed.

Answer (score 6):

You have built an inifinte loop. That's where your out of memory warning is coming from.

```
my $message="test"; 
open(XML,$sendXML); 
while ("
    <includeFilterSets>
        <filterSet>
            <filter>
                <filterName>VERSION_NAME</filterName>
                <operator>
                    <name>In</name>
                </operator>
                <value>10.0u</value>
                </filter>
        </filterSet>
    </includeFilterSets>") {
} 
close XML;
```

I don't know what you would like to achieve with this, but it's not what you want to do. This snippet does the following:

- set `$test` to 'test'
- open a file handle to the filename in `$sendXML`
- as long as the XML snippet is true, do nothing (this is always the case, thus infinite loop)
- the `close` is never reached.

The rest of your code is ok.

What you want to do is this. I've left out the filehandle stuff.

```
my $message = <<'XML';
<includeFilterSets>
        <filterSet>
            <filter>
                <filterName>VERSION_NAME</filterName>
                <operator>
                    <name>In</name>
                </operator>
                <value>10.0u</value>
            </filter>
    </filterSet>
</includeFilterSets>
XML

my $webpage="http://example.com/";
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new; 
my $response = $ua->post($webpage, Content_Type => 'text/xml', Content => $message);
if ($response->is_success) {
    print $response->decoded_content;  # or whatever
}
else {
    die $response->status_line;
}
```

---

One word of advice: Always `use strict` and `use warnings`, and look at three-argument opens and lexical filehandles. This will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: well how can i parse my XML using POST as i want to get rid of infinite loop you have mentioned.

Comment: well after running the suggested code by simbabque i am getting the error message as "Content type can't be consumed". what shoudl i do to get rid of this problem.Please suggest.

Comment: Simbabque can you please help me further.

Comment: @user2260105 do you have documentation for the webservice you are coding against? What does it say? Does your error message come from the service at all? The POST request has nothing to do with parsing anything. You parse the response (but right now you don't). What are the files in your example code for? Do you want to read input from a file?

Comment: i have remodified the code and i am getting the "400 URL must be absolute"

Comment: I modified the code and i m getting "400 URL must be absolute" error message.

Comment: Do you know the difference between an absolute and a relative URL? Try to figure that out, and you'll see what the problem is. ;-)

Comment: I have resolved that absolute URL issue but i am getting the error message as :<error><errorCode>24</errorCode><errorMessage>Method: Search not allowed on this server. You can&apos;t call query api methods on this instance</errorMessage></error>

Comment: Sounds like you're not allowed to do what you do. Now this is something we cannot help you with I'm afraid. On the bright side, you did learn something. :)

Comment: Yes u r right @simbabque, surely i did learn something.But does my issue means that server is making me restricted what i am supposed to do or is there any glitch in my program.

Comment: @ simbabque. my problem is resolved now and it's functioning perfectly. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: @ simbabque now i have problem with multipart POST.

Comment: Open a new question for this. Stack Overflow is a q&a plattform for specific problems, not a forum. If this answer was helpful, please mark it as correct by clicking the checkmark on the left below the votes. Thank you.